# Trigger query with OLD keyword does not work

Tags: mysql, triggers

Here's my query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER orderitemsdelete BEFORE DELETE ON orderitems
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE items SET quantity=quantity+OLD.quantity where itemid=OLD.itemid;
```

The **orderitems** table consists of following columns:

```
orderitemsid
itemid
quantity
```

The **items** table consists of following columns:

```
itemid
quantity
```

I want to increase the quantity on **items** table as much as is deleted from the **orderitems** table, but somehow cannot get it to work.

There are no errors generated, and the trigger seems to fire, but somehow doesn't work.

I think there may be a problem with the OLD keyword, because it doesn't highlight in the mysql query browser as do the other keywords such as INSERT, CREATE, TRIGGER, NEW etc.

What might be the problem, and the solution?

Do I need to mention that the delete query on orderitems is fired as a casacade from a foreign key of of another table? Does that matter?